# Cannot show items on a listView (using a ResourceCursorAdapter and SQLite)

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm a newbie on Android, excuse me if basic question

what I try is populate a listView from SQLite using a cursor filled with data from an adapter (a class that inherits from ResourceCursorAdapter).

I readed and tried some examples but cannot make listView show any row.

what I can see debugging is that "bindView" method of "PedidosAdapter" (derived from ResourceCursorAdapter) is NEVER called... not sure why.

can someone help me to resolve this?

what I do:
- I created table with _id field (otherwise error)
- I derived main activity from listActivity and activity and on both not show nothing...

I uploaded test code on https://www.dropbox.com/s/g1dlff4esafgeiy/PedidosLH.zip if like to check it direct without read pasted code here...

```
LAYOUT -- "activity_main.xml"

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.i4.pedidoslh.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_view" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PedidosSQLiteHelper pdb =
                new PedidosSQLiteHelper(this, PedidosSQLiteHelper.DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

        SQLiteDatabase db = pdb.getWritableDatabase();
        // Generate example data...
        if(db != null)
        {
            //Insertamos 5 usuarios de ejemplo
            for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
            {
                //Generamos los datos de prueba
                int cod_mov_cc = i;
                int nr_comprob = 10000+i;
                int nro_clie = 5000+i;

                //Insertamos los datos en la tabla ENCPEDID
                db.execSQL(
                        "INSERT INTO " + PedidosSQLiteHelper.TABLE_ENCPEDID + " ("
                                + PedidosSQLiteHelper.KEY_ENCPEDID_COD_MOV_CC + ", "
                                + PedidosSQLiteHelper.KEY_ENCPEDID_NR_COMPROB + ", "
                                + PedidosSQLiteHelper.KEY_ENCPEDID_NRO_CLIE + ") " +
                        "VALUES (" + cod_mov_cc + "," + nr_comprob + "," + nro_clie + ")");

                db.execSQL(
                        "INSERT INTO " + PedidosSQLiteHelper.TABLE_ITMPEDID + " ("
                                + PedidosSQLiteHelper.KEY_ITMPEDID_NRO_ITEM + ", "
                                + PedidosSQLiteHelper.KEY_ITMPEDID_COD_MOV_CC + ", "
                                + PedidosSQLiteHelper.KEY_ITMPEDID_NR_COMPROB + ", "
                                + PedidosSQLiteHelper.KEY_ITMPEDID_COD_PROD + ", "
                                + PedidosSQLiteHelper.KEY_ITMPEDID_CANTIDAD + ", "
                                + PedidosSQLiteHelper.KEY_ITMPEDID_PENDIENTE + ", "
                                + PedidosSQLiteHelper.KEY_ITMPEDID_PORC_CUMPL + ", "
                                + PedidosSQLiteHelper.KEY_ITMPEDID_DESCRIP + ") " +
                        "VALUES ("
                                + i + ","
                                + cod_mov_cc + ","
                                + nr_comprob + ",'"
                                + "prd" + i + "',"
                                + i + ","
                                + i + ","
                                + "0" + ","
                                + "'" + "desc" + i + "'" + ")");
            }

            //Cerramos la base de datos
            db.close();
        } // db != null

        fillData();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {      ...     }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { ... }

    private void fillData() {

        PedidosSQLiteHelper pdb =
                new PedidosSQLiteHelper(this, PedidosSQLiteHelper.DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

        SQLiteDatabase db = pdb.getReadableDatabase();

        String sql = "SELECT _id, cod_mov_cc, nr_comprob FROM ENCPEDID";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

        if (c.getCount() == 0) android.util.Log.w("deb", "fillData COUNT = 0");
        startManagingCursor(c);

        // ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.listPessoas, PESSOAS);
        PedidosAdapter pa = new PedidosAdapter(MainActivity.this, c);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        lv.setAdapter(pa); // setListAdapter(pa) if listActivity...

        stopManagingCursor(c);
        c.close();
    }

    private class PedidosAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {

        public PedidosAdapter(Context context, Cursor cur) {
            super(context, R.layout.row_pedidos, cur);
            //mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cur, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            return li.inflate(R.layout.row_pedidos, parent, false);
            //View item = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_pedidos, null);
        }

        @Override // this method is never called!!
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cur) {

            TextView txtPedido = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPedido);
            TextView txtCliente = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCliente);
            //CheckBox cbListCheck = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.list_checkbox);

            txtPedido.setText(
                    cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("PEDIDO")));

            txtCliente.setText(
                    cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PedidosSQLiteHelper.KEY_ENCPEDID_NRO_CLIE)));

            //cbListCheck.setChecked((cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(Datenbank.DB_STATE))==0?     false:true))));

            //String idname = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            //view.setTag(idname);

        } // bindView
    } // adapter
} // class
```

row_pedidos.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark" -->
    <TextView android:text="Mensaje principal"
        android:id="@+id/txtPedido"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <!-- android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark" -->
    <TextView android:text="mensaje debajo"
        android:id="@+id/txtCliente"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these lines from fillData():

```
stopManagingCursor(c);
c.close();
```

After passing the cursor to your ResourceCursorAdapater, that cursor needs to remain open since it is what the adapter reads data from to create its views as you scroll the list. If you close it, it becomes invalid and the adapter no longer has any data to show, hence your ListView is empty.

The call you have to startManagingCursor allows the activity to take care of managing the cursor's lifecycle based on the activity's lifecycle. If your activity is stopped it will automatically call deactivate() on it, if your activity is restarted it will call requery() for you and when your activity is destroyed, it will be closed for you. So you don't need those two lines of code because the system is taking care of all these things for you.

Comment: you don't know how I was tried to make it work without luck, never thinked that cursor have to be opened during activity lifecycle, I missunderstood how adapter works -without read too much documentation about this- , because usually on desktop apps have to retrieve data, it keep on memory and close connection...

Comment: thanks you SO MUCH for answer me and for guide me about what I was made VERY wrong, I was struggling with this for more than 3 days.
If can abuse of your help and you can recommend me some book to read about android programming will be very appreciated :D thanks again.

Comment: You're very welcome. What you did wasn't very wrong, just a simple error/misunderstanding and we all make those. I personally read 'Professional Android 4 Application Development by Reto Meier' as a starting point but be warned that some of the content is becoming out of date. There are many books out there - look on Amazon, read the reviews and make your choice...